# Querying Elasticsearch securely from client side

Tags: java, android, security, elasticsearch

Is it possible to securely pass the authorization headers for elasticsearch and query on client side with Java Android? 
Even though it gives admin privileges to everyone and requires login credentials is there any way to use it securely without a backend?

Answer (score 0):

Not free. 
elasticsearch got some user login security tools but this is not free.

Comment: There are some free alternatives: https://readonlyrest.com/ + https://search-guard.com

Comment: @Val, didnot know search-guard thanks for the info. readonlyrest is not free if i remember, but maybe depends of usage.